# reledmac - Error with option parapparatus and nested footnote

Tags: reledmac

Thanks to the option `parapparatus`, the text of a footnote with the "normal" arrangement is allowed to contain paragraph breaks, like this:

```
\edtext{Lemma}{%
\Afootnote{First paragraph.
  \par                       % paragraph break
Second paragraph.}}
```

However, I get an error message whenever the footnote in question is nested within (the `\edtext` of) another footnote:

```
\edtext{Lemma Bigger FN...
%
  \edtext{Lemma Nested FN.}{%
  \Afootnote{First paragraph.
  \par                         % paragraph break
  Second paragraph.}}
%
...end of lemma.}{%
\Afootnote{Text Bigger FN.}}
```

The error message is:

```
Runaway argument?
{Lemma Bigger FN... \edtext {Lemma Nested FN.}{\Afootnote {First para\ETC.
./MWE_parbreak_in_footnote.tex:19: Paragraph ended before \showlemma was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.17 \Afootnote{Text Bigger FN.}}
```

This is the classic error that stems from inserting a paragraph break into a macro that is non-`\long`.

AFAICS, `parapparatus` redefines `\Xfootnote{}` to be `\long`, i.e., it can contain paragraph breaks.
But this mechanism *doesn't work if it is nested* within another footnote. (Regardless of the arrangement of the "bigger" footnote, be it "normal" or "paragraph"...)

Is this intended? The manual doesn't mention it (§6.2.4). Or is it a bug resulting from the interaction of `\edtext` (non-`\long`) with the `\long` argument of `\Xfootnote`?

Or am I doing something wrong?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noend,nofamiliar,noeledsec,parapparatus]{reledmac}
\Xnotefontsize[A]{\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
\edtext{Lemma Bigger FN...
%
  \edtext{Lemma Nested FN.}{%
  \Afootnote{First paragraph.
  \par                         % paragraph break
  Second paragraph.}}
%
...end of lemma.}{%
\Afootnote{Text Bigger FN.}}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

(FWIW: We use \Afootnotes to render the author's own marginal notes on his text. When we need to comment on these notes, since reledmac cannot *append a critical footnote to a footnote*, we need to "simulate" our usual critical apparatus of \Bfootnotes. That is, we print our commentary *within the foonote text*, in a new paragraph, in a smaller font.
Anyway, this can also be obtained *without using `parapparatus` and a par-break*, f.i. a simple `\newline` will do.)

Comment: It is obvisouly a bug insided reledmac. It is easy to fix. Please open a github issue.

Comment: Thanks! I have just opened an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 2.37.2 of reledmac, which will be sent today or tomorrow on CTAN, solves this issue.

Comment: I feel my question has been answered. The problem I pointed to was a bug; the package author has found the issue and fixed it.

Comment: Yes, I don't know what I could write more...